# How to work with long strings in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I recently started working with Tailwind and I can't figure out how to work with long text and grids in general.

Now my problem looks like this.
[image]

If you start typing long text or some long words or phrases, then the text block starts to break everything

```
<div class="flex align-center justify-between mt-1" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px">
    <div class="col-span-1 flex-none">
        <img class="mt-1 mb-1" src="{{$link->icon}}" style="width:50px; border-radius: {{$link->rounded}}px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-span-10 text-center flex items-center">
        <div class="ml-3 mr-3">
            <h4 class="text-ellipsis" style="{{$link->title}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="up" class="col-span-1 flex items-center flex-none">
        <img src="https://digiltable.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/2021/09/Sexy-lady-logo-Pornhub-logo.png" style="width:50px; border-radius: {{$link->rounded}}px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this because your title is wrapped inside `style`

Change:

```
<h4 class="text-ellipsis" style="{{$link->title}}</h4>
```

to

```
<h4 class="text-ellipsis" >{$link->title}</h4>  Place it here
```